# MYSQL Data can,t be controlled

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

I fetch data from database, the process is working good but the data flow will not be controlled..
Below is my code.........

```
<?php session_start();
include 'conn.php';
include '../includes/layouts/header.php';
$sql="SELECT * FROM signup";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
?>
    <div id="main">
        <div id="navigation" >
            <ul class="nav">
                <li><a href="selected_user.php">Manage Users</a></li>
                <li><a href="manage_users.php">Post New Anousment</a></li>
                <li><a href="message.php">Messages</a></li>
                <li><a href="setting.php">Setting</a></li>
                <li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
            </ul>
            &nbsp;
        </div>
        <div id="page">

            <h2>Admin Menu</h2>
            <p>Welcome to Admin Area</p>

            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th><strong>ID</strong></th>
                    <th><strong>FirstName</strong></th>
                    <th><strong>LastName</strong></th>
                    <th><strong>UserName</strong></th>
                    <th><strong>Email</strong></th>
                    <th><strong>Department</strong></th>
                    <th><strong>ID#</strong></th>
                    <th><strong>Phone #</strong></th>
                    <th><strong>Password</strong></th>
                    <th><strong>Address</strong></th>
                </tr>
<?php  while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){?>

    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $rows['Id']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $rows['First_Name']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $rows['Last_Name']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $rows['Username'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $rows['Email']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $rows['Department']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $rows['Employe_Id']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $rows['Phone']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $rows['Password']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $rows['Address']; ?></td>
    </tr>

<?php } ?>
            </table>
        </div>
        </div>






<?php include '../includes/layouts/footer.php' ?>
```

the main problem is the password field as it is encrypted by using sha512, therefore it is too long and i want to show it in table, so can any one tell me what to do? how to control the flow of password field.. because it distrub the webpage alignment also....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would you show encrypted password? Since it is only one-way encryption you won't have the password anyways (without using some rainbow tables..). If you really want to get it tho, you can use `substr($password, 0, NUMBER_OF_CHARACTERS_YOU_WANT_TO_SHOW)` for getting the encrypted password cut, and on hover show it all in something like [tipsy](http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/tipsy/).